# "Lato" Google Font vertically stretched in Safari vs Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, safari, webfonts, google-webfonts

I'm using for some years Lato from Google Fonts, and my site used to look essentially identical between Safari & Chrome (on the Mac). Lato was rendered as expected on both systems.

I upgraded from High Sierra to Mojave, and now Safari (v13 in both cases) seems to be rendering Lato weirdly at low point sizes. It looks like for point sizes around 12px to 16px, it's vertically stretching the font and it looks bad.

(Safari and Chrome on iOS render it correctly.)

The Google demo page for Lato renders it correctly and as expected at those point sizes in both browsers:
https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Lato

Note: this is not the common "font weight" issue between browsers. The smoothing options in the example code match this issue between browsers so they look the same.

Below is a representative stripped down code HTML example that demonstrates the differences, along with a graphic with the text overlaid so you can more easily see the differences.

[image: Lato rendering between Safari & Chrome on macOS]

(Watch, for example the "14px" text and observe the vertical stretching going on.)

I've been playing with whatever aliasing, subpixel rendering, font smoothing options I can but nothing is changing the rendering of Lato to make it look as expected in Safari. (Non-retina screen). It just makes my site look stretched and ugly here and it's mildy disturbing(!)

Anyone have an idea of what's going on here?

Thanks

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,400italic,700,700italic,900&subset=latin' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<style>
body{
    background:#262626!important;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    font-family:Lato;
    color: white;
}

p {
    font-weight: 400;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    font-weight: 700;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h4 style='font-size: 10px;'>H4 Example marmite dumplings 10px</h4>
<h4 style='font-size: 12px;'>H4 Example marmite dumplings 12px</h4>
<h4 style='font-size: 13px;'>H4 Example marmite dumplings 13px</h4>
<h4 style='font-size: 14px;'>H4 Example marmite dumplings 14px</h4>
<h4 style='font-size: 16px;'>H4 Example marmite dumplings 16px</h4>
<h4 style='font-size: 20px;'>H4 Example marmite dumplings 20px</h4>
</body>
</html>
```

Note: If I preview in Responsive Design mode, looking at it in simulated Retina view (2x), the font seems to shrink and look more correct than 1x view. This leads me to think this is some weird macOS Non-Retina scaling issue that just seems to affect Lato. But why does it only affect my page, when it renders correctly on both browsers on Google's Lato demo page? Strange...

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue, though I do see very minor kerning differences at 20px+ — nothing like your sample image though. Are you 100% positive that your server has no local version of Lato that might be loading before the CDN serves the file? I know it's not *logical* that Chrome and Safari may act differently for this, but it's good to eliminate the possibility as Google is always dickering with something or the other.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and for checking - yes, I'm not worried about the minor kerning differences.

I also checked on another, non-retina Mac running Sierra and Safari 12 on the same network, and that also shows the stretched Lato. It also behaves the same whether my site is served from my web host, or whether it's served from my local dev host.

Really strange. I have no local versions of Lato I know and empty as many local caches as I can but I will have a hunt around...

Comment: In addition to the simple `font-family` declaration, have you tried to **set an `@font-face`?** This would declare the source (`src`) of the used font file directly and would allow you to circumvent the possibility of the browser choosing a second version of a font from a long-forgotten file.

Comment: The behaviour is the same using font-face (which is all the Google font api is returning anyway - a list of font-face declarations loading the fonts from fonts.gstatic.com)

Comment: Ok, I've hosted and served the fonts locally, and there's no change in behaviour. Safari is still rendering those point sizes incorrectly. But it's obviously not *incapable* of doing it, as they are rendered correctly in Safari on Google's on web fonts page. It's really strange.

Comment: Still haven't found a solution to this. It turns out Safari here is slightly vertically stretching *all* fonts (it's just more noticeable at heavier weights and certain sizes, and it's not just Lato). It's definitely to do with the font rendering at 1x non-retina resolution, but nothing I found, including all and any settings for smoothing and anti-aliasing, seems to change this behaviour.